# regex failing to grab closing bracket in end of line

Tags: regex

I am trying to use the regex `\b(\w*):(\S*)\b` on the text `key:value number:2 stuff:color(color)`, but the third time grabs only `stuff:color(color` without the closing bracket. Can anyone explain why please?

Comment: What exactly are you talking about? Sorry, started dealing with regex only recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing last `\b`:

```
\b(\w*):(\S*)
```

You cannot match word boundary after `)` as that is not a word character.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aS9hR0/2)

Comment: Yes you can test this on regexpal also. Same regex will work there as well.

Comment: However regexpal is only Javascript regex tester where as regex101 lets you test PCRE and Python regex as well.

Comment: I generally use both - regex101 has that nifty feature that also shows the groups, but pal has a comfier UI.